# Break out data of a cell into multiple columns SQL

Tags: sql

I have a column with data like this

| Tag |
| --- |
| 1.16.1.20220803.1.1411 |
| 1.16.1.20220808.1.1081 |

and I would like to break it up like this so I can join it to a different table that uses these fields

| Tag | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.16.1.20220803.1.1411 | 1 | 16 | 20220803 | 1 | 1411 |
| 1.16.1.20220808.1.1081 | 1 | 16 | 20220808 | 1 | 1081 |

I have no clue how to do this, I tried string split however that only lets me accomplish this if I give it a string myself

I need it to dynamically do it with the values my query returns without me manually inputting the tag string

I don't even know if this is possible, and couldn't find anything with my google searches.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: what is the RDBMS that you are using?  mySQL? Oracle? sqlServer?

Comment: sqlServer, I work for a company that has their own RDB's, I'm new to this and don't know the difference between mySQL and sqlServer, we us Microsoft SQL server management studio